# Combining two CSS elements

Tags: html, css

How would I combined the follow into one block

```
#idOne td, th {
  ......
}

#idTwo td, th {
  ......
}
```

I tried

```
#idOne td, th,
#idTwo td, th {
  .....
}
```

but the`th` is included as its own.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "the `th` is included as its own"?

Comment: Oh, you have `th` in there twice... you could remove one of them.

Comment: You need to realize that its a comma separated list of selectors. You want a unique list of selectors. Were you thinking #idOne td, #idOne th, #idTwo td, #idTwo th { ... }? Otherwise all th will get the styling in the block.

Comment: @bryjohns yeah thats what I was thinking, just couldnt get it out right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the parent for each of the td and th tags:

```
#idOne td, #idOne  th, #idTwo td, #idTwo th {
  ......
}
```

Comment: for some reason i thought the parent was carried over. my mistake. thanks

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut Unfortunately css isn't so clever. If you use less or sass you can nest your your selectors so it would be something like #idOne, #idTwo { th, td { ... } }. That's probably what you were thinking css would do for you as the idea its very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Given the question example, the correct way would be this:

```
#idOne td, #idTwo td, th {
  .....
}
```

But I've a feeling that the example might not be quite as you intend.